# How to insert record on yii framework using get method?

Tags: yii

Hi I am new in yii framework. I would like to know if how can I insert data using Get method on yii framework ? Because I have created a a script but the record does not add into my database.

here is my URL

```
http://testdomain.com/?name=test&number=1234567&email=test@test.com
```

here is my script:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
        $model=new Userinfo;

        if(isset($_GET['name'])){

            $model->name=$_GET['name'];
            $model->number=$_GET['number'];
            $model->email=$_GET['email'];

            if($model->save()){         
              echo "Success";                   
            }
       }
}
```

e.g ( http://testdomain.com/?name=test&number=1234567&email=test@test.com )

i would like to insert data on my database table 
table name = userinfo

Fields:

name     number     email

Thank you. For your help.

Comment: Can we see your model? And what is the error displayed (you could try to display models errors if($model->save()){...}else{var_dump($model->getErrors());}

Comment: don't do that, never allow modification to the database from GET request

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic idea:

```
$model = new Userinfo;
$model->name = $_GET['name'];
$model->number = $_GET['number'];
$model->email = $_GET['email'];
if ($model->validate()){
    $model->save();
} else {
    print_r($model->errors);
}
```

This is with no validation. You would most likely put this in a Controller/Action

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$model->insert();
```

your code seems working fine as i check it on my working application, check your model and database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you never see "Success", meaning that the [save()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail) method is returning false.  Note that `save()` does not throw an exception when validation fails, it just returns false.

Since you're not seeing "Success", this means that validation failed in your model, so check the model rules.